# Is method scope important when defining methods inside a class?

Tags: python, class, methods, scope, nameerror

I have a method that returns four variables that is used to create a rectangle. But the function uses another methods to get some values.

So my rectangle_points() method gets two points from x_value() and y_value() respectively, but for some reason I cannot make a function call to x_value() from inside rectangle_points() I get an NameError: name 'x_value' is not defined

```
from random import *

class Rectangle:
    def x_value():
        return choice(range(0, 800, 10))

    def y_value():
        return choice(range(0, 600, 10))

    def rectangle_points():
        x1 = x_value()
        y1 = y_value()
        x2 = x1 + 10
        y2 = y1 + 10
        return x1, y1, x2, y2

    print('for rectangle points are {}'.format(rectangle_points()))
```

expected results for now should be to print out the four points but I get an NameError: name 'x_value' is not defined. ps I assume I will get the same problem for the line y1 = y_value() if it were to reach that line.

Comment: You really need to familiarize yourself with the basics of Python classes. The [official tutorial is a good place to start](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: You seem to have accidentally put your code inside an unnecessary class. If you unindent it and delete the class, your code will work better.

Comment: Khelwood makes a good point, you aren't using any internal state, so why are you even making a class?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga class is not finished but I'm trying to implement the game of life in python

Answer (score 1):

It is just a quick fix. When creating methods for a class, **self** is always called during its initialisation.
This then allows you to use other methods from the same class when creating a new method.
This should fix your code!

```
from random import *

class Rectangle:
    def x_value(self):
        return choice(range(0, 800, 10))

    def y_value(self):
        return choice(range(0, 600, 10))

    def rectangle_points(self):
        x1 = self.x_value()
        y1 = self.y_value()
        x2 = x1 + 10
        y2 = y1 + 10
        return x1, y1, x2, y2
rec = Rectangle()
print('for rectangle points are {}'.format(rec.rectangle_points()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @JBirdVegas suggestion I'd like to provide you with the full answer.

```
from random import choice

class Rectangle:
    def x_value(self):
        return choice(range(0, 800, 10))


    def y_value(self):
        return choice(range(0, 600, 10))


    def rectangle_points(self):
        x1 = self.x_value()
        y1 = self.y_value()
        x2 = x1 + 10
        y2 = y1 + 10
        return x1, y1, x2, y2


r = Rectangle()
print('for rectangle points are {}'.format(r.rectangle_points()))
```

You have to tell the interpreter to reference to the class own function. You can achieve this by adding the `self`

This way the interpreter knows it's referencing to itself i.e `Rectangle.x_value` and not just `x_value`. As previously suggested in the comments I advise you to look into the documentation for further details but this should fix all your problems for now.

EDIT: I'd like to add that using `import *` isn't always the best solution, you could change it to `from random import choice` to avoid bloat and possible errors if libraries have the same named object

Answer (score -2):

You're so close!!!

Just add `self` like `self.x_value()`

And if first param should be `self`

`def x_value(self):`

The `self` means the function is an instance member and not a class member.

And `print` should probably not be indented but that doesn't matter as much

Comment: Maybe try to articulate a more informative answer? I mean it's correct but, short and non explanatory?

Comment: Haha your right didn't see they were functions... Updated... Didn't want to just give the answer but your right I was too short with the explanation